Having trouble figuring out why none of the values are being transfered from one sheet to another in VBA code
I wrote this program in VBA that opens another excel sheet that the user can enter the name of, and then the program is supposed to open the user specified sheet, find the needed data, and copy and paste it into the specified locations on the new sheet. The program opens the correct sheet, but does not copy any data to the new sheet and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated!
Sub Automated_Fill()
'
' Automated_Fill Macro
'

    '
    ' Get customer workbook...
    Dim customerBook As Workbook
    Dim filter As String
    Dim caption As String
    Dim customerFilename As String
    Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

    ' active workbook is the target
    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    ' get the customer workbook
    filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
    caption = "Please Select an input file "
    customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

    Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)

    ' copy data from customer to target workbook
    ' Grocery Data
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim sourceSheetGroSel As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheetGroSel = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    targetSheet.Range("C9").Value = sourceSheetGroSel.Range("J8").Value
    targetSheet.Range("C17").Value = sourceSheetGroSel.Range("K8").Value

    Dim sourceSheetGroLoad As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheetGroLoad = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(3)

    targetSheet.Range("C10").Value = sourceSheetGroLoad.Range("J5").Value
    targetSheet.Range("C11").Value = 0
    targetSheet.Range("C18").Value = sourceSheetGroLoad.Range("K5").Value
    targetSheet.Range("C19").Value = 0

    Dim sourceSheetGroLTO As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheetGroLTO = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(4)

    targetSheet.Range("C12").Value = sourceSheetGroLTO.Range("J12").Value - sourceSheetGroLTO.Range("J8").Value - sourceSheetGroLTO.Range("J9").Value
    targetSheet.Range("C13").Value = 0
    targetSheet.Range("C20").Value = sourceSheetGroLTO.Range("K12").Value
    targetSheet.Range("C21").Value = 0
    targetSheet.Range("G12").Value = sourceSheetGroLTO.Range("J8").Value + sourceSheetGroLTO.Range("J9").Value

    Dim sourceSheetGroRec As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheetGroRec = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(5)

    targetSheet.Range("G13").Value = sourceSheetGroRec.Range("J5").Value
    targetSheet.Range("G21").Value = sourceSheetGroRec.Range("K5").Value

    ' Perishable Data

    Dim sourceSheetPerSel As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheetPerSel = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(6)

    targetSheet.Range("G99").Value = sourceSheetPerSel.Range("J10").Value
    targetSheet.Range("G107").Value = sourceSheetPerSel.Range("K10").Value

    Dim sourceSheetPerLoad As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheetPerLoad = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(7)

    targetSheet.Range("G100").Value = sourceSheetPerLoad.Range("J5").Value
    targetSheet.Range("G108").Value = sourceSheetPerLoad.Range("J5").Value

    Dim sourceSheetPerLTO As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheetPerLTO = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(9)

    targetSheet.Range("C102").Value = sourceSheetPerLTO.Range("J10").Value sourceSheetPerLTO.Range("J7").Value
    targetSheet.Range("G102").Value = sourceSheetPerLTO.Range("J7").Value
    targetSheet.Range("C110").Value = sourceSheetPerLTO.Range("K10").Value

    Dim sourceSheetPerRec As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheetPerRec = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(8)

    targetSheet.Range("C103").Value = sourceSheetPerRec.Range("J5").Value
    targetSheet.Range("C111").Value = sourceSheetPerRec.Range("K5").Value

    ' Freezer Data

    Dim sourceSheetFrzSel As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheetFrzSel = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(10)

    targetSheet.Range("C144").Value = sourceSheetFrzSel.Range("J6").Value
    targetSheet.Range("C152").Value = sourceSheetFrzSel.Range("K6").Value

    Dim sourceSheetFrzLTO As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheetFrzLTO = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(11)

    targetSheet.Range("C147").Value = sourceSheetFrzLTO.Range("J5").Value
    targetSheet.Range("G147").Value = sourceSheetFrzLTO.Range("J4").Value
    targetSheet.Range("C155").Value = sourceSheetFrzLTO.Range("J5").Value
    targetSheet.Range("G155").Value = sourceSheetFrzLTO.Range("J4").Value

    Dim sourceSheetFrzRec As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheetFrzRec = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(12)

    targetSheet.Range("G148").Value = sourceSheetFrzRec.Range("J5").Value
    targetSheet.Range("G156").Value = sourceSheetFrzRec.Range("K5").Value

    ' Close customer workbook
    customerWorkbook.Close

End Sub


Is the line at targetSheet.Range("C102") with the added sourceSheetPerLTO.Range("J7").Value at the end a copy paste error (should at least have gotten an error code if not)? Have you gone through the code step by step?

If you aren't getting an error, then the cell values are being transferred, so either the source cells are empty or you are looking at the wrong sheet.

After Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1) add line MsgBox targetSheet.Parent.FullName & " " & targetSheet.Name, , "targetSheet"

I am not getting any errors, and I have gone through the code step by step but cannot find anything wrong, but then the first sheet that needs the data from the other sheet just stays empty...

How about targetWorkbook.Save before closing?

Is it possible you have any hidden sheets in the Target workbook?  If Yes and they're at the beginning of the tab order that would explain what you're seeing.  Safer to use the tab name or the sheet's codename instead of the sheet index.

Try setting the targetWorkbook to thisWorkbook instead of ActiveWorkbook if this subroutine is in the targetworkbook. If this is some add-in that uses the current ActiveWorkbook and that is necessary, is the user always using worksheets(1) or will they possibly have multiple worksheets they're copying data to, in which case, you could set the worksheet to targetWorkbook.ActiveSheet or you could always create a new sheet.
Set targetWorksheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=targetWorkbook.worksheets(targetWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))

